# Retrieve the monitors configuration from the command line

Tags: linux, command-line, multiple-monitors

I am making a script that needs to access the computer's monitor(s) configuration. How can I do that? Is there a command or a file I could read where I can access this information?

At the moment, I do

```
xwininfo -root
```

But I only have the total resolution and not the details (What I need is the resolution of each screen individually).

Thanks!

Comment: do you have access to the xserver while executing the script? do you want to know the limits of the hardware (the monitors)? do you want to know what resolutions are configure in Xorg.conf?

Comment: I want to know what resolutions are configured in Xorg.conf, except that as I am running Fedora 14, by default I don't have a Xorg.conf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your video driver supports it, `xrandr` will display the available and current resolutions for all displays.